# Are pushMatrix() / popMatrix() capable of stacking?

Tags: java, opengl

If you don't understand what I'm asking, I mean -

```
glPushMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
glPushMatrix();
glPushMatrix(); // push matrix 4 times
glTranslatef(...);
//do stuff
glPopMatrix(); // pull it up 1, so we can do more stuff
glTranslatef(...);
// do stuff
glPopMatrix(); // and again, and again, etc
glTranslatef(...);
// do stuff
glPopMatrix();
glTranslatef(...);
// do stuff
glPopMatrix();
```

Would everything still work out?

Comment: Still couldn't understand what you are asking, and what you mean. Can you share the context in which you are doing all this?

Comment: That is .. the nature of a stack. It's always best to start with some documentation, reference or tutorial. (Note that SO is was not in the previous list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `glPushMatrix` pushes the current matrix of the current matrixmode (`GL_PROJECTION`, `GL_MODELVIEW`, etc.) to a matrix stack, `glPopMatrix` pops the first one back. There are separate stacks for each matrixmode.

It doesn't look there's an old enough official OpenGL man page to have the documentation on this method, but this site came up as one of the first results and contains the same text: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/glPushMatrix/

According to that page, it looks like `GL_MODELVIEW` stack is guaranteed to be at least 32 matrices deep, and all the other ones at least 2 deep. On modern cards they're probably much higher. You can poll the exact number by calling `glGet` with the proper parameter for stack depth, i.e. `GL_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH` or `GL_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH`, etc.

Also, the matrix stack was deprecated a long time ago in favor of user-managed matrices. If you're writing a small program or just learning, it's totally fine to use deprecated OpenGL. Just felt like I should mention it for the sake of completeness regarding OpenGL matrices.